# How can I find project charter resources?

Tags: project-charter

I am new as a project manager. I was told that I have to write a project charter for a new project that I will have to manage. Are there any templates explaining what has to be in that charter?

I understand it as some kind of contract, but a contract between who? How can I precisely define the scope of the projects? The deadlines?

Answer (score 3):

### Finding Information and Templates for Project Charters

Wikipedia does a good job of explaining the purpose of a [project charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_charter). It even includes a link to a [sample template](http://www.hitdocs.com/project-charter-template-docx/), although any given template may or may not suit a particular project's needs.

A template is *not* a substitute for understanding how to charter a project. However, searching the web for some variation of:

- project charter template,
- PRINCE2 project charter, or
- PMBOK project charter

will turn up lots of resources on the subject, including a wide variety of templates.

Comment: I have updated it, I will accept it but you will have to have some patience, there could come other answers I think?